# word VBA cropping images behave differently between office2013/2016 local and office365 on a remote desktop

Tags: vba, ms-word, office365, crop, remote-desktop

I have a VBA code that inserts images in a word file.
after setting the (fixed) width and height of the image. i use CropBottom etc. to crop the image.

example:

```
With .PictureFormat
                With .Parent
                    .Width = 809
                    .Height = 525
                End With
                .CropBottom = 67
                .CropLeft = 38
                .CropTop = 9
                .CropRight = 13 + ((10 - cntBor) * 71) 'width boring=71
            End With
```

(these are pictures taken of up to 10 objects that have to be pasted and cropped in a word file, cntBor is the actual number of objects on the current picture and determines the cropdistance. (one object is 71px width after resizing.) )

this is working as intented in office 2013 and 2016 on a local computer.

on an external desktop server running office 365 (guess the newest one, i can't see a version number) the image width and height seems to be set allright but the cropping is acting very differently. all values seem a bit off and if the cropvalue is high it's even more off.

would someone know what might be causing these differences?

i checked the microsoft website and other website to see if there has been a change in cropping behaviour but i can't seem to find anything.

I have been fiddling with the crop values. and only thing i can say that it's incremental. so the higher the crop number is the more it is not accurate. any changes i make will make the cropping localy wrong.

Comment: "is there a way to force the cropping to use pixels, either on an older word and the newer word?" - No, the only value that Word has ever used is points, not pixels.

Comment: okay then i must be mistaken about that part, i will edit my post regarding this, but than is it possbile the point values are handled differently?